# Web service getting <br /> instead of JSON

Tags: php, android, bufferedreader

I was developing a simple PHP page to generate a JSON text so I can test my application (the actual server is being developed by another guy) and I face a strange error. My PHP page is only this:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$trip = array ('trip' => array  ( array ('departureStation' => $_GET['from'],
                'arriveStation' => $_GET['to'],
                'departureTime' => '08:00',
                'arriveTime' => '11:00',
                'date' => $_GET['date'],
                'duration' => '3',
                'distance' => '80',
                'price' => '5',
                'changeLine' => false,
                'waitTime' => '0',
                'passengers' => '13'),
                array ('departureStation' => $_GET['from'],
                'arriveStation' => $_GET['to'],
                'departureTime' => '11:00',
                'arriveTime' => '14:00',
                'date' => $_GET['date'],
                'duration' => '3',
                'distance' => '80',
                'price' => '5',
                'changeLine' => false,
                'waitTime' => '0',
                'passengers' => '29'),
                array ('departureStation' => $_GET['from'],
                'arriveStation' => $_GET['to'],
                'departureTime' => '17:00',
                'arriveTime' => '20:00',
                'date' => $_GET['date'],
                'duration' => '3',
                'distance' => '80',
                'price' => '5',
                'changeLine' => false,
                'waitTime' => '0',
                'passengers' => '45')));

echo json_encode($trip);
?>
```

I checked and it returns a valid JSON, but when I do

```
URL url = new URL("http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/consult.php" + param);

con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setReadTimeout(10000);      /* milliseconds */
con.setConnectTimeout(15000);   /* milliseconds */
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setDoInput(true);

con.connect();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8" ));
payload = reader.readLine();
```

The payload variable only gets a `<br />`

I know that is something on PHP because I enter on the page, copied the output, come back on the PHP code again and just put

```
$echo 'json_copied_from_the_page_here';
```

and it worked, the payload is reading the page correctly. So I'm curious, why this happened?

Comment: You should check e.g. with wireshark and the emulator what you are downloading.

Answer (score 1):

You are only reading a single line, the rest of the output should be behind that line.

Try this

Edit: can't use += on strings.

```
String temp = null;
String output = "";
while ((temp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    output = output + temp;
} // end while
```

see the output if it works.

Comment: Yes it **should** if you have errors a <br /> will be printed after before the error message in the default php debug format which is exactly what is happening here. I might be wrong.. lets see.

Comment: True. Shouldn't payload be instantiated anyway? `String payload = ..` or something like that?

Comment: i guess he already did it before the code block posted if not he wouldn't be able to read the br, the first readline would've initiate the string though.

Comment: I tried to do the +=. My activity simply froze but no exceptions were thrown, strange.
Anyway, the output suppose to be just a line. So there's no sense on doing that, I guess.

Comment: Can you debug the app?I suspect there are exception thrown on the Php script.